# Pip doesn't update to latest python version

Tags: python, pip

Python is on version 2.7.3, but when i try to upgrade python through "pip" i get this:

```
$ pip install --upgrade python
Requirement already up-to-date: python in /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload
Cleaning up...
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip` installs python packages, not python itself.

Changing a system python version is a bad idea. To install an additional python version system-wide you could use your system package manager such as `apt-get`.

To manage personal python installations you could use [`pythonz`](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz).

Comment: Related is https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/583 I may try get the pypi Python entry fixed or better still removed. Pip won't be able to build and install it anyway as it doesn't use `./configure && make` rather than `setup.py`